# How to fix : Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server. For more information (NotServedByPagesError)

Tags: github, dns, jekyll, github-pages, cname

So I am trying to setup a custom domain with my github pages site. I have followed the steps as in [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site). I am using [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en) for the domain.

1. I have added the **A record** to my DNS records at the registrar pointing to all of the four IP addresses

[image]

2. I have added the **CNAME record**

[image]

and I have checked them too

[image: A]

but I am still getting this error

[image: error]

UPDATE: it just loads into a white screen now
[image: white screen]

My site link is `https://xharuke.github.io/haruke/` and not `https://xharuke.github.io` is that what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059217/how-to-fix-domain-does-not-resolve-to-the-github-pages-server-error-in-github

Comment: Have added the domain name to GitHub and created a CNAME file with the domain name? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPGi1IHQxFM

Comment: also happening to me. would be good to update if there was a fix.